# Sum of independent identically distributed random variables uncorrelated but not necessarily independent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Problem.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables such that they are independent and identically distributed. Suppose that $U = X + Y$ and $V = X - Y$. Show that $U$ and $V$ are uncorrelated but not necessarily independent.

Furthermore, show that $U$ and $V$ are independent when $X$ and $Y$ have normal distribution.

**Attempt at a solution.** Let $F_{X}(x)$ be the distribution function of $X$. Similarly, for $Y$ let $F_{Y}(y)$. Suppose $F(x, y)$ is the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

I know that $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed iff. $F_{X} = F_{Y}$.
I know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff. $F(x, y) = F_{X}F_{Y}$.
I know that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated iff. $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$.

To show that $U$ and $V$ are uncorrelated we show $\mathbb{E}[UV] = \mathbb{E}[U]\mathbb{E}[V]$. This is true iff

$$\mathbb{E}[(X + Y)(X - Y)] = \mathbb{E}[X + Y]\mathbb{E}[X - Y]$$

iff

$$\mathbb{E}[X^{2} - Y^{2}] = \mathbb{E}[X + Y]\mathbb{E}[X - Y] = (\mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[Y])(\mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[Y])$$

iff

$$\mathbb{E}[X^{2}] - \mathbb{E}[Y^{2}] = (\mathbb{E}[X])^{2} - (\mathbb{E}[Y])^{2}.$$

After this I am stuck because I know that in general it is not true that $\mathbb{E}[X^{2}] = (\mathbb{E}[X])^{2}$.

Comment: Use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are iid.

Comment: For a simple example of not-necessarily-independent, flip a coin twice and let $X$ be $1$ if first flip is H and $0$ otherwise, and $Y$ similarly for the second flip. Then if $X+Y=2$ we know that $X-Y=0$ which shows that $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are not independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for the first part: it is assumed, though not stated explicitly, that $EX^{2} $ and $EY^{2}$ are finite. To show that covariance is $0$  you need $EX^{2}-EY^{2}=(EX)^{2}-(EY)^{2}$ (as you have already observed). Just write this as $EX^{2}-(EX)^{2}=EY^{2}-(EY)^{2}$ or $var(X)=var(Y)$. This equation holds becasue $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. with Cauchy distribution. Then it is easy to verify that $Ee^{i(tU+sV)}=Ee^{itU} Ee^{isV}$ is not satisfied.  [The characteristic function of Cauchy distribution is $e^{-|t|}$]. This gives an example where $U$ and $V$ are not independent.

The last part  is a well known result which  involves solving the functional equation $\phi (t+s)\phi (t-s)=\phi(t)^{2} |\phi (s)|^{2}$.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and solve and if I have any remaining questions, then I will come back and ask.